# Jasper Report Table column breakpoint

Tags: jasper-reports, breakpoints

My Report Table is above 20 columns, is there a option to display the whole table on one page with a breaktpoint between column 10 and 11?

Comment: What kind of table is it?, crosstab, in detail band a jr:table component. Show some jrxml.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Its a normal jr:table in detail band.
Are there any options to display one table above 2 or 3 Rows in one Detail Band?

Comment: Sorry I can not really understand what you are after?, above 2 or 3 rows, breakpoint between column 10 and 11, try to update your question edit it, then ping me if you want me to have a look